# View loaded but not its components

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view

I was working on my iPad app, and suddenly, **I dont see anything in my first view** I did a test to know if it loaded, with `NSLog` and it did really load.

But it doesn't show me its components, buttons for example, I pressed the home button on the simulator, make the app on the background and enter again, and then, I can see my components.

Thank you

Comment: You probably have added your code into viewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

In your app delegate did you set root view controller ?

or

just implement

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {

     // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
     [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
     NSLog(@"recieved memory warning");
}
```

to know if view could not be loaded because of memory level.

Comment: I set the root view controller like this: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[AuthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AuthViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Answer (score 0):

Check your NIB file to ensure the .m file is hooked up to it correctly. Make sure the View is assigned to the files owner.

Comment: When I am on the mainWindow.xib, i found that their aren't any object (apart of window that isn't linked to anything), and the file's owner isn't linked to anything?! I don't know how does it happen, because yesterday, everything works correctly, can you tell me how to fix it please? thanks